# Can't get Scenario Object with @Before Hook

Tags: java, cucumber

I'm trying to get the current scenario object with the `@Before` hook because I want to display its name.
But when I try to do so I get following exception:

```
cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: 
    When a hook declares an argument it must be of type    \
    cucumber.runtime.ScenarioResult.
public void sefa.sqlpmi.CucumberStedDefs.afterCucumberScenario( 
    gherkin.formatter.model.Scenario) throws java.lang.Exception
```

My code looks like this:

```
@Before
public void beforeCucumberScenario(Scenario scenario) throws Exception{
    System.out.println(scenario.getName());
}
```

It seems that this works for many others.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you import `cucumber.api.Scenario` and not `gherkin.formatter.model.Scenario`. The second one produces the exception that you mention.

Comment: Thanks so far!
But there's still a problem.. cucumber.api.Scenario can't be resolved..
This might be because of a missing dependency, but i cannot find the one that is necessary.

Do you know which one I need?

Comment: Should be in cucumber-core. What version of are you using?

Comment: Thanks so far!
But there's still a problem.. 
maybe with my dependencies
with this dependency i can resolve cucumber.annotation.en.* but not cucumber.api.Scenario
  <dependency>
   <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
   <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
   <scope>test</scope>
   <version>1.0.11</version>
  </dependency>

if i change it to 
  <dependency>
   <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
   <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
   <version>1.1.3</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>

I can resolve cucumber.api.Scenario but not cucumber.annotation.en.*

Comment: You need to add cucumber-core lib to your project

Comment: Thanks again, but there are still problems.. When i add the cucumber-core dependency I get following Exception: 'java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: cucumber.cli.Main' My denpendencies are the following: cucumber-core v.1.2.4 and cucumber-java 1.2.4

Comment: Okeey.. I got it: the problem was with my IDE -> IDEA the default settigs for main class where cucumber.cli.Main. I changed this to cucumber.api.cli.Main and now it works! Thanks for helping!!